# How to fix: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.android.youtubedownloader, PID: 9291

Tags: java, android, crash

Please I need assistance.
I was creating a youtube downloader app, after launch on my device, It displayed application error. I traces the error message from logcat.

```
2021-12-14 05:21:17.718 9291-9291/com.android.youtubedownloader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.youtubedownloader, PID: 9291
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.hardware.display.DisplayManager cannot be cast to android.app.DownloadManager
    at com.android.youtubedownloader.MainActivity$1.onUrisAvailable(MainActivity.java:46)
    at at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YouTubeUriExtractor.onExtractionComplete(YouTubeUriExtractor.java:15)
    at at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YouTubeExtractor.onPostExecute(YouTubeExtractor.java:146)
    at at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YouTubeExtractor.onPostExecute(YouTubeExtractor.java:38)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6275)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to you're trying to cast DisplayManager object to DownloadManager which is not possible to solve this you need to do like following.

**Java**

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
```

Comment: 2021-12-14 06:40:08.235 20875-20875/com.android.youtubedownloader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.youtubedownloader, PID: 20875
    java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/MyDrama.mp4: Neither user 10195 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)

Comment: That's what I got in the logcat after making the correction!

Comment: I added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to my manifest file to solve the second error! Big Thanks to you!

Comment: This is due to your app can't access the external storage and after Scoped Storage there are many changes to access the things. you can find blogs related to it.